# Different behavior between render function & template in Vue 3 Nested Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

Using Vue 3 Nested Router, I setup a Structure like this:

```
root1
  └ Parent Route (router-view with Render Function)
      └ Child Route [FAIL TO RENDER]
root2
  └ Parent Route (router-view with Template)
      └ Child Route [FINE]
```

In my mind, these two ways are interchangeable, but the actual performance is different. What's the problem?

Furthermore, is

`render() { return Vue.h("router-view") }`

&

`template: "<router-view></router-view>"`

are really Completely the Same in Vue 3?

Here is the [Example](https://codepen.io/miswanting/pen/LYZvGov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be :

```
  component: {
    render() {
      return Vue.h(VueRouter.RouterView) 
    }
  },
```

instead of  :

```
render() { return Vue.h("router-view") }
```

custom components should be used with plain name in `PascalCase` format.